I know this isn’t the right way to test causality but what would the right method be for this?
My first guess would be to some sort of interrupted time series or regression kink design. P.S. PDMP is prescription drug monitoring programs. Prescription rates is for opioids. The graphs of each are are so drastic that you already know just by looking,I’d still like to know the right way to statistically prove/refute the graphs which strongly suggest that the PDMP reduces RX rates, has no effect on RX OD deaths but drastically spiked illicit OD deaths.

